# Why do I get conflicts when I am downloading the same files in Android by using Download Manager?

Tags: android, download, download-manager

When I am downloading the mp4 video Files using Download Manager, its getting downloaded. After Downloading process is completed I could be able to play the mp4 video Files.

In my app, I given the Title name is, File Downloader and video file name is video.mp4

That is, request.setTitle("File Downloader");

When I am downloading at second time, Downloading gets failed. Since same Title name that is File Downloader.

Why is it getting Failed? But when I am deleting previous video files and clicked download button, it's fine. Downloading completely and could be able to play the videos.

My doubt is, why same Downloading files are couldn't be downloaded again and again and its geting conflicted . I mean, failed .

Only once I could be able to download the files and playing well not at the second time which has same Downloading file names.

Error is:

> In Emulator - Download Failed, Cannot Download since the Destination File already exists!

[Android Docs- ERROR FILE ALREADY EXISTS !](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS)

By above link, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: rename the previous video file with a different name and download the same again

Comment: Sorry, When Iam downloading the same Url its getting conflicted ! When Iam checking in browser by pasting that URL - several times I could be able to play the videos. but not in Emulator and Android phone

Comment: can you please post the logcat logs..

Comment: 05-03 11:49:26.726: I/System.out(5904): Downloads : 172
05-03 11:49:35.537: I/System.out(5904): SD cardfalse

Comment: 05-03 11:49:13.867: W/KeyCharacterMap(29480): No keyboard for id 0
05-03 11:49:13.867: W/KeyCharacterMap(29480): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-03 11:49:26.726: I/System.out(5904): Downloads : 172
05-03 11:49:35.537: I/System.out(5904): SD cardfalse
05-03 11:52:03.576: I/System.out(6870): Downloads : 174
05-03 11:52:11.397: I/System.out(6870): SD cardfalse
05-03 11:52:42.836: I/System.out(6870): Downloads : 176
05-03 11:52:53.167: I/System.out(6870): SD cardfalse

Comment: What mistake I have done here - I couldnt be able to download the same URL after once and downloaded well. Kindly can anyone say me please?

Comment: @Praful and Raghunandan: I checked in Emulator - Download Failed, Cannot Download since the Destination File already exists !

Comment: I've also occurred this issue. even though I've already renamed the files, but still throw this `ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXIST` did you already have a solutions?